# Best solution for client side templating

Tags: client-side-templating

I am working on a project with very strict company security rules which means I am unable to create CMS pages using a local server. As a result the company still makes use of old technologies such as shtml includes. This means that node.js is out of the picture. I have been researching angular.js, handlebars.js and various other means of client-side template solutions. However, most require some sort of third party tool (outside of node) in order to get these working. I am only allowed to use CSS/javascript libraries on flat pages.

Any suggestions?